# Issues with Createing a form update button from a controller method in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey all i am building out a CAD App in Rails 4 Ruby 2.

> **Background:**

I have a form field that is a f.time_select, i would like to replace that with a button that says on scene. When Pressed I would like it to update the unit_on_scene column in my calls table and then redirects me to the show.html.erb page.

**My Button Looks Like:**

```
<%= link_to "On Scene", update_unit_on_scene_call_path class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm' %>
```

My routes.rb Looks Like:

```
  resources :calls do 
    collection do
      get 'history'
    end
    member do
      patch :update_unit_on_scene
    end
  end
```

**That then gives me this link in Rake Routes:**

```
update_unit_on_scene_call PATCH  /calls/:id/update_unit_on_scene(.:format) calls#update_unit_on_scene
```

**My Controller Method Looks Like:**

```
def update_unit_on_scene
  @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  @call.unit_on_scene = DateTime.now
  @call.save

  respond_to do |format|
    if @call.update(call_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "On Scene Time Successfully Updated. - You Are Now Logged Out Of Service" }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
end
```

The Problem I have right now is that when I Push the button it gives the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/calls/3/update_unit_on_scene"
```

as if it is looking for another page??

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have never ventured down this road before.

Thanks.

**EDIT # 1:**

> **Associated Warning when Button Clicked:**

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in CallsController#update_unit_on_scene
param is missing or the value is empty: call

Extracted source (around line #107):
105
106
107
108
109
110

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id, :user_id, :unit2_os, :unit2_cl, :unit3_os, :unit3_cl, :unit4_os, :unit4_cl)
    end
end
```

> **Server Log:**

```
Started PATCH "/calls/3/update_unit_on_scene" for ::1 at 2015-11-22 01:38:49 -0700
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    Processing by CallsController#update_unit_on_scene as HTML
      Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"hH4juJAS7bxs+HHPjSuEDLpucwAh2i2QODH8DvF3JQVxhzhet1AcAs6xzib6AezrlLJ3yZrHLea5ey8206gIqA==", "id"=>"3"}
      Call Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "calls".* FROM "calls" WHERE "calls"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "calls" SET "unit_on_scene" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "calls"."id" = $3  [["unit_on_scene", "2015-11-22 08:38:50.027783"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-22 08:38:50.031354"], ["id", 3]]
       (6.4ms)  COMMIT
    Completed 400 Bad Request in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 9.9ms)

    ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: call):
      app/controllers/calls_controller.rb:107:in `call_params'
      app/controllers/calls_controller.rb:89:in `block in update_unit_on_scene'
      app/controllers/calls_controller.rb:88:in `update_unit_on_scene'


      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.0ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.2ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (53.4ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.9ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (42.8ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.8ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
      Rendered /Users/TaurenLTD1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (96.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) helper will make a `GET` request unless a method is specified.

So, you need to specify the method (`method: :patch`) in your `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "On Scene", update_unit_on_scene_call_path(@call), class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm', method: :patch %>
```

Also, change your controller action to this:

```
  def update_unit_on_scene
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    @call.unit_on_scene = DateTime.now

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "On Scene Time Successfully Updated. - You Are Now Logged Out Of Service" }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Ok so when i use that way i get the following error

Comment: param is missing or the value is empty: call

Comment: yeah, it should be: `update_unit_on_scene_call_path(@call)`

Comment: even with the (@call) in there it is still the same error as before.

Comment: Remove this line: `if @call.update(call_params)` in the action. This is creating problem. As you have defined `call_params` such a way that it requires to have a `call` key in the params hash, but for this `update_unit_on_scene` action you don't have that.

Comment: Just do: `if @call.save . . . `

Comment: Sir, This has been the bane of my existence for the last week.. I thank you once again for your assistance here! my eyes were bleeding reading the Rails API trying to sort this out!! That works great!

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad that I could help. Sometimes you just need a little help to get going and then you can go a long way :) If you are stuck with any Ruby/Rails related problem and need some help, you can hire me for a short session at codementor. I do mentoring there in my free time: https://www.codementor.io/rakib

Comment: Hey thats awesome! thanks I will most certainly take you up on that offer!